# How to do integration testing for clojure/ring/selenium/leiningen?

Tags: clojure, webdriver, continuous-integration, leiningen

I have a clojure/ring web application which I want to test with clj-webdriver. Is there a simple way to run the ring webserver and then run the tests such that they target the ring instance?

I'm thinking of a usage something like:

$ lein with-ring test

I have two ideas so far:

1. write a custom higher order leiningen plugin. Seems too complicated. Does a similar plugin already exist?
2. write a Makefile rule which starts ring, runs lein test, find&kill the ring process - too complicated/hacky

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using `clojure.test` you can call [`use-fixtures`](http://richhickey.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html#clojure.test/use-fixtures) to start/stop your server from within the tests, e.g.:

```
(use-fixtures
  :once
  (fn [f]
    (let [server (ring.adapter.jetty/run-jetty
                    #'your-app
                    {:port 1234 :join? false})]
      (try
        (f)
        (finally
          (.stop server))))))
```

Just adjust start/stop logic to your preferred webserver (jetty in this example; http-kit would be very similar). If you replace `:once` with `:each` you'll even have a fresh server instance for each single test.

Comment: I've just tested it and it works nice but I have one small comment: you have to call run-jetty with :join? false like this: {:port 1234 :join? false} otherwise it blocks.

Comment: @vidi: Thanks! I added the key to the answer.